# Sum of Nested List with Empty List Explanation

Tags: python

I am working through a `gensim` tutorial and have come across something I don't understand. `texts` is a nested list of strings:

```
In [37]: texts
Out[37]:
[['human', 'machine', 'interface', 'lab', 'abc', 'computer', 'applications'],
 ['survey', 'user', 'opinion', 'computer', 'system', 'response', 'time'],
 ['eps', 'user', 'interface', 'management', 'system'],
 ['system', 'human', 'system', 'engineering', 'testing', 'eps'],
 ['relation', 'user', 'perceived', 'response', 'time', 'error', 'measurement'],
 ['generation', 'random', 'binary', 'unordered', 'trees'],
 ['intersection', 'graph', 'paths', 'trees'],
 ['graph', 'minors', 'iv', 'widths', 'trees', 'well', 'quasi', 'ordering'],
 ['graph', 'minors', 'survey']]
```

and `sum(texts,[])` gives:

```
Out[38]:
['human',
 'machine',
 'interface',
 'lab',
 'abc',
 'computer',
 'applications',
 'survey',
 'user',
 'opinion',
 'computer',
```

The list goes on for a few more lines but I omitted the rest to save space.  I have two questions:

1) Why does `sum(texts,[])` produces that outcome (i.e. flattens the nested list)?

2) Why is the output displayed strangely - one element of per line? Is there something special with this output (...or I suspect it might be my iPython behaving strangely).  Please confirm if you see this as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because adding lists together concatenates them.

```
sum([a, b, c, d, ..., z], start)
```

is equivalent to

```
start + a + b + c + d + ... + z
```

So

```
sum([['one', 'two'], ['three', 'four']], [])
```

is equivalent to

```
[] + ['one', 'two'] + ['three', 'four']
```

Which gives you

```
['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']
```

---

Note that `start`, by default, is `0`, since by default it works with numbers, so if you were to try

```
sum([['one', 'two'], ['three', 'four']])
```

then it would try the equivalent of

```
0 + ['one', 'two'] + ['three', 'four']
```

and it would fail because you can't add integers to lists.

---

The one-per-line thing is just how IPython is deciding to output your long list of strings.

Comment: In your first line `sum([a, b, c, d, ..., z], start])` you have a stray `]`.  Where should the `[` be?

Comment: @mchangun: oops my bad. It just shouldn't have been there at all.

Comment: Thanks - really good answer.  Now reading the docs makes sense =)

Answer (score 3):

First, it's being displayed that way because you're using ipython.

Second, think about how `sum` may be defined. Are you familiar with functional programming?

If you were to define it yourself, you'd write something like:

```
def sum(lst, start):
    if len(lst) == 1:
        return lst[0] + start
    else:
        return lst[0] + sum(lst[1:], start)
```

Running this on a list of lists is equivalent to saying

```
[['a','b'] + ['c','d'] + []] # for example
```

which results in:

```
['a','b','c','d']
```

or, in other words, flattens the list.

Comment: Makes it very clear why sum(lst, start) != sum(start,list).  I naively thought they were the same!  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Because you can perform addition (and other operations) on lists as well, so you are essentially adding lists together to create one giant list.

```
['a'] + ['b'] = ['a','b']
```