# Grouping every nth lists of list in Python

Tags: python, list, group-by, list-comprehension

I am attempting to group the every 4 lists into one list in python. Whenever I scrape the data it returns to look like this:

```
[['Ethnicity /Sex'], ['DOB /Age'], ['Booking Date'], ['Release Date'], ['AMERICAN (US)', 'FEMALE'], ['04/07/1968', '52 years old'], ['1/2/2020 4:34 AM'], ['1/2/2020 8:47 PM']]
```

I would like for the output to now become:

```
[['Ethnicity /Sex', 'DOB /Age', 'Booking Date', 'Release Date'], ['AMERICAN (US)', 'FEMALE', '04/07/1968', '52 years old', '1/2/2020 4:34 AM', '1/2/2020 8:47 PM']]
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Your second sublist has more than 4 items. Shouldn't it have 4?

Comment: @IoaTzimas look carefully at the original list, some of the elements have more the 1 string in it

Comment: _Any ideas?_ Is there a specific issue? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
l = [['Ethnicity /Sex'], ['DOB /Age'], ['Booking Date'], ['Release Date'], ['AMERICAN (US)', 'FEMALE'], ['04/07/1968', '52 years old'], ['1/2/2020 4:34 AM'], ['1/2/2020 8:47 PM']]
res = res = [sum(l[i:i+4], []) for i in range(0, len(l), 4)]
```

Where the output is:

```
[['Ethnicity /Sex', 'DOB /Age', 'Booking Date', 'Release Date'], ['AMERICAN (US)', 'FEMALE', '04/07/1968', '52 years old', '1/2/2020 4:34 AM', '1/2/2020 8:47 PM']]
```

1. An explanation on the way I merge the lists is available at [Sum of Nested List with Empty List Explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19453451/sum-of-nested-list-with-empty-list-explanation)
2. An explanation of list comprehension is available at https://treyhunner.com/2015/12/python-list-comprehensions-now-in-color/

Comment: isn't `j` always `i + 4`?

Comment: simlified..:  `res = [sum(lst[i*4:(i+1)*4], []) for i in range(len(lst) // 4)]`

Comment: @thebjorn you are absolutely right, I will fix it. The effect of not fully focused. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'd use reduce,

```py
import functools
l = [['Ethnicity /Sex'], ['DOB /Age'], ['Booking Date'], ['Release Date'], ['AMERICAN (US)', 'FEMALE'], ['04/07/1968', '52 years old'], ['1/2/2020 4:34 AM'], ['1/2/2020 8:47 PM']]
[functools.reduce(list.__add__, l[:4])] + [functools.reduce(list.__add__, l[4:])] # [['Ethnicity /Sex', 'DOB /Age', 'Booking Date', 'Release Date'], ['AMERICAN (US)', 'FEMALE', '04/07/1968', '52 years old', '1/2/2020 4:34 AM', '1/2/2020 8:47 PM']]
```

Comment: Yours was very close, it grouped the first 4 lists, but it did not continuously group 4 lists throughout the entire list. I perhaps mis-phrased the question a tad. I really appreciate it though, and I will be sure look into reduce, for I have never used it before. Thanks!

Comment: I think my output and yours are the same, no? What I get from my answer is

[['Ethnicity /Sex', 'DOB /Age', 'Booking Date', 'Release Date'],
 ['AMERICAN (US)',
  'FEMALE',
  '04/07/1968',
  '52 years old',
  '1/2/2020 4:34 AM',
  '1/2/2020 8:47 PM']]

Comment: You are correct, i didn't specify my question well enough... , there are N lists after the first two, and I was asking to group every four lists continuously. Imagine if there were 1000 lists after the lists I posted. I'm sorry for the lack of clarity

Answer (score -1):

without list comprehensions:

```
lst = [['Ethnicity /Sex'], ['DOB /Age'], ['Booking Date'], ['Release Date'], 
       ['AMERICAN (US)', 'FEMALE'], ['04/07/1968', '52 years old'], ['1/2/2020 4:34 AM'], ['1/2/2020 8:47 PM']]

res = []
while lst:
    res.append(sum(lst[:4], []))
    lst = lst[4:]

print(res)
```

output

```
[['Ethnicity /Sex', 'DOB /Age', 'Booking Date', 'Release Date'], ['AMERICAN (US)', 'FEMALE', '04/07/1968', '52 years old', '1/2/2020 4:34 AM', '1/2/2020 8:47 PM']]
```